# How to determine if vue.js is used in a site or web app?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Is there a command in console? Or a tell tale sign like `ng` directives used in angular for vue that let you know if it's used in a site or app?

Comment: `typeof window.Vue` would do it, I'd think.

Comment: In my test app writing `typeof window.Vue` returns the string `"function"`

Comment: There are other ways, using browser extensions, [for chrome](https://www.google.com/search?q=chrome+extension+detect+framework&rlz=1C5CHFA_enBD695BD695&oq=chrome+extension+to+detect+&aqs=chrome.3.69i57j0l5.14254j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: Yes, and it'll be `"undefined"` on a site without Vue. Try running that here on StackOverflow, for example.

Comment: Sites that bundle Vue (e.g. with webpack) will not have it globally available on `window`

Comment: @Matt Good point, thanks. [Here's how the Vue devtools detect its presence](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools/blob/24812e5542bb359a06a3e62379fd8c8633ae6034/shells/chrome/src/detector.js#L9).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Vue dev tools [uses three different approaches](https://github.com/vuejs/devtools/blob/da62deffcc374e5a7cb5e8a57c088857a24d4737/packages/shell-chrome/src/detector.js#L14).

One of the approaches is this:

```
// Method 3: Scan all elements inside document
const all = document.querySelectorAll('*')
let el
for (let i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
  if (all[i].__vue__) {
    el = all[i]
    break
  }
}
if (el) {
  let Vue = Object.getPrototypeOf(el.__vue__).constructor
  while (Vue.super) {
    Vue = Vue.super
  }
  win.postMessage({
    devtoolsEnabled: Vue.config.devtools,
    vueDetected: true,
  }, '*')
  return
}
```

Comment: For Vue 3, replacing `__vue__` with `__vue_app__` worked for me. There's also `window.__VUE__`, but that's set even if I only use the Pinia store without mounting anything which wasn't desired for what i wanted to do.